# Can I add C++ DLL in a ASP MVC application

Tags: c++, asp.net-mvc, dll, dllimport

I am trying to add a reference to a DLL built using C++ in ASP.Net MVC 5 application.
I want to call functions in DLL from the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. The key here is "platform invoke".

1. You need to create a class holding the DLL methods (Win32 in the sample)
2. You need to define the prototypes/signatures of the DLL methods, using the DllImport annotation
3. Now you can call those methods

This sample is taken from the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/consuming-unmanaged-dll-functions):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Win32 {
     [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
     public static extern IntPtr MessageBox(int hWnd, String text, 
                     String caption, uint type);
}

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void Main() {
       Win32.MessageBox(0, "Hello World", "Platform Invoke Sample", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !  I had tried to import a DLL built for x64 platform and use it with  MVC application being built in debug mode and **Any CPU** for platform. So I faced the problem. That's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any native or unmanaged DLL can be used with ASP MVC applications. The **builds should be targeting the same Platform**. If a C++ DLL has been built for x64 platform, then the application(web/console) importing it should also be built for the same configuration. 
See the post from @bdongus for importing using DllImport. Also the servers should run on the same platform.
[image]